# Component not waiting for http request payload

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm new to using Postgres and I am trying to work out how to update multiple rows in a single query from a given array.

The data coming into the query would look something like:

```
[{category: 1, id: 1, name: 'steve', age: 25, addresses: []},
{category: 1, id: 2, name: 'james', age: 26, addresses: []},
{category: 1, id: 3, name: 'josh', age: 22, addresses: []}]
```

So from that array I'd update 3 rows in a single query.
Something like,

```
for (const row of array) {
   UPDATE users(name, age, addresses) VALUES(row.name, row.age, row.addresses)
}
```

Obviously that won't work, but something that achieves what that loop is trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is in JavasScript, the incoming array contains objects